# String containing all object properties with no nulls

Tags: java, string, null

I got these objects in constructor.

```
cars.add(new Car(2016, "honda", "civic"));
cars.add(new Car(2017, "Lamborghini", "aventador"));
cars.add(new Car(2000, null, "caravan"));
cars.add(new Car(2010, "dodge", null));
```

I need to return all the data from it in the following format:
hondacivicLamborghiniaventadorcaravandodge

My function is:

```
public String listAllCars()
{
    String result;
    result = null;

    if(cars == null)
    {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("c cannot be null");
    }

    for(Car car: cars)
    {

        if(car.getMake() != null || car.getModel() != null) 
        {
            result += car.getMake() + car.getModel();
        }

    }

    return result; 
}
```

But I end up with `nullhondacivicLamborghiniaventadornullcaravandodgenull` instead of `hondacivicLamborghiniaventadorcaravandodge`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to append each field if it's not `null` independently. For *compactness* you may use `Objects.toString`. For efficiency, a simple `if` will do.

If you are ok with using Streams API:

```java
public String listAllCars() {
    if (cars == null) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("c cannot be null");
    }

    return cars.stream()
            .map(c -> Objects.toString(c.getMake(), "")
                    + Objects.toString(c.getModel(), ""))
            .reduce("", (a, b) -> a + b);
}
```

Or, using the imperative style, but with a `StringBuilder`:

```java
public String listAllCars() {
    if (cars == null) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("c cannot be null");
    }

    StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();

    for (Car car : cars) {
        result.append(Objects.toString(car.getMake(), ""));
        result.append(Objects.toString(car.getModel(), ""));
    }

    return result.toString();
}
```

Or, without the `StringBuilder`:

```java
public String listAllCars() {
    if (cars == null) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("c cannot be null");
    }

    String result = "";

    for (Car car : cars) {
        result += Objects.toString(car.getMake(), "");
        result += Objects.toString(car.getModel(), "");
    }

    return result;
}
```

Comment: Can we do it without maps and Stringbuilder?

Comment: Yes, added to the answer, but bear in mind that StringBuilder is the recommended way of appending strings in Java.

Answer (score 0):

You are checking whether any one of make or model are not null. But, your case requires you to check for both make and model individually and concatenate if present.

```
for(Car car: cars) {
    if(car.getMake() != null) { result += car.getMake(); }
    if(car.getModel() != null) { result += car.getModel(); }
}
```

Comment: initialize result to empty string instead of null. i.e., `""`

Comment: initialized. I also need to add 2 cars data that has no null

Comment: I don't seem to understand your requirement clearly. Can you be more clear?

Comment: If you need both make and model of the car not null, you can do `if (car.getMake() != null && car.getModel() != null)`. So, this means that you'll add the car to `result` only if it has both the make and model. If you are fine with one of the fields being null, you can use the above code.